# CGContextDrawImage and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, bitmapimage

Sometimes CGContextDrawImage causes "bad access error" executing following code We are unable to find cause. Is there anyone has been encountered same error using "CGContextDrawImage" ?

```
    let bytesPerPixel = 4;
    let bytesPerRow:UInt = UInt(bytesPerPixel) * UInt(CG_Width)
    let bitsPerComponent:UInt = 8;

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)

    var pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(4)



    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel,
        UInt(CG_Width), UInt(CG_Width), bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)



    let cgRect:CGRect = CGRectMake (0,0,CGFloat(CG_Width),CGFloat(CG_Width)) as CGRect



    CGContextDrawImage(context, cgRect, imageRef)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your pixel buffer, you're only allocating 4 bytes, which is enough for a 1x1 bitmap.  Since presumably, CG_Width (where's CG_Height used?) isn't 1, so when you lie to `CGBitmapContextCreate` about the size of the buffer and then draw into it, you're scribbling all over random memory.  Change the buffer allocation to:

```
var pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.alloc(bytesPerRow * CG_Height)
```

and then change the context creation to use the right height as well:

```
let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel,
    UInt(CG_Width), UInt(CG_Height), bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)
```

If you're actually intentionally creating a square bitmap, change my `CG_Height` to `CG_Width`

Comment: It is always pleasure  reading something written by somebody knows what he is talking about. For me I am just glad I can see what you meant. PS: CG_Width is equal to CG_Height.  So when allocation changed as bytesPerRow * CG_Width * CG_Width problem has been solved.

Comment: Should just need `bytesPerRow * CG_Width` then since rowBytes already factors in CG_Width once.